# Jetty deployment not working on Raspberry PI

Tags: java, jetty, raspberry-pi

I installed jetty on my Raspberry PI
I used the JVM provided by oracle (early acess 8 with hardware float calc)

But even the simplest of deployments doesn't work.

I moved several files into $JETTY_HOME/webapps, some of the demo webapps or anything else (*.war's, folders with index in it and what not)

NONE get deployed?
Restart... still nothing.
I can access the main page but it only shows the jetty welcome page. Can't even get that to NOT be shown.

Its jetty 9 so i dont see the problem?

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: I'd first try with stable stuff, like Java 7. See if that works...

Comment: Please provide _much_ more information. You basically just said "It doesn't work". Please provide output/error logs or your jetty.xml and similar stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why (clean install) but there were actually two jetty directories and I was acting in the WRONG one. 
I fiddled in /usr/jetty***/...
I had to fiddle in /usr/share/jetty/...